# Problema para mostrar todos los objetos json relacionados a un modelo por su id en RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un método `show` que debe *renderizar* objetos `json` de tres modelos que están relacionados entre sí por sus `id`.

Los modelos son los siguientes:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :areas
end

class Area < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :area_contacts
end

class AreaContact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :area
end
```

Donde company tiene un company_id y se relaciona a través de este campo con el modelo area, y area_contact se relaciona con el modelo area a través del campo area_id.

Mi método `show` en el archivo _companies_controller.rb_ está definido así:

```
def show
  @areas = @company.areas
  @area_contacts =  AreaContact.includes(:area).find_by_area_id(@areas.ids)

  render json: { company: @company,
                 areas: @areas,
                 area_contacts: @area_contacts
               }
end
```

El problema es que solo me trae el primer `area_contact`, sin importar cuantos tenga relacionados al `area_id` que se trae la consulta cuando llamo a la compañía. Es decir si consulto por el `company_id = 1`, me traerá todas las `areas` que tengan `company_id = 1`, y a su vez debería traerme todos los `area_contact` relacionados al `area_id` que se trajo la consulta por el `company_id = 1`, pero solo me trae el primero.

Por lo que pienso que el problema está definido en esta parte de mi código:

```
@area_contacts =  AreaContact.includes(:area).find_by_area_id(@areas.ids)
```

Por favor, agradezco cualquier ayuda o comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en el método `find_by_area_id` (justo en la línea que identificaste con el error) ya que este siempre devolverá el primer resultado que encuentre; para que te devuelva todos los resultados deberás utilizar `where` en su lugar:

```
@area_contacts =  AreaContact.includes(:area).where(area_id: @areas.ids)
```